# create or replace PACKAGE BODY not honored

Tags: sql, oracle, build, compiler-errors, package

The command create or replace `PACKAGE ...` is not being honored.

I have had numerous times where if I use `@` command in a driver file on a Package Body or Spec, where the old version of the code remains intact.  The new version doesn't get uploaded.  This has even happened when I drop the package in question, and use `@THIS_PACKAGE_SPEC.SQL`.  The old package will come back.  The error logs show the package loaded and compiled normally.

One way to deal with this is to load the `THIS_PACKAGE_SPEC.SQL` into developer and execute it by itself.

Another is to drop the old package, shut down and restart Oracle SQL Developer then proceed normally.

This problem has exhibited itself using both Oracle SQL Developer, and SQLPlus.  In Unix and Linux environments.

Anyone else experience this?

Comment: Nope, never heard of anything like that. Are you sure it's looking for the file where you expect, and isn't just finding an old version somewhere in [SQLPATH](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_two.htm#sthref63)? Is the 'driver file' invoked just as `@file` - or as `@/path/to/file` and you expect anything that script invokes to be founf in that same path?

Comment: I suppose it is possible that Oracle has a bug that causes it to internally do a flashback query to find the old version of code when you do a `create or replace package`.  And that this bug would follow you across clients and operating systems.  That seems highly, highly unlikely however.  It seems much more likely that the file you are executing actually has the old code when you run it.  Perhaps you have it open in a text editor and you haven't saved the changes you've met.

Comment: The only time I have experienced this was hen DevA and DevB were for some reason working on the same package, one was editing the package using an external text editor then running in the script, and the other was editing the package via TOAD. The TOAD guy would click "Run" and the SQLPlus guy would save the script then run through SQLPlus. So both were overwriting each other. The TOAD guy lost out when he clicked refresh, and got the scripted version, at which point he lost his changes. That, or perhaps someone is running an import and including the PLSQL. I wouldnt rule out mischief either.

Comment: I've encountered this before. It was (in HAL's words) "attributable to human error"... I was editing a version of the script in one location, but my SQL*Plus session was running from a different folder.

Comment: I did once work at a place with a fully automated deployment process. It would periodically take the latest release from the repository and deploy it to the main dev server. We would switch it off selectively when we were working on the code. If we forgot to switch it off, we'd soon find our changes were lost next time the auto deploy scripts were run.